# How can I code something that can find the title on a website

Tags: html, web-crawler

How can I code something that goes to a website and looks for the title tag then shows that data?

Comment: Use an HTML or XML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="hi"></div>
```

**JS (with JQuery)**

```
$.ajax({
url:'https://crossorigin.me/' +
    'https://myurl.com',
    type:'GET',
    success: function(data){
       var x = "";
       x = data.replace(/[^]*<title>/,"");
       x = x.replace(/<\/title>[^]*/,"")
       $("#hi").html(x);
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/d4ewfs79/3/

Comment: Thanks this is what i needed :)